# Randomize a div position

Tags: javascript, html, random

I've made a program where you press a button and a div positions itself randomly.

```
function Init()
{
   div = document.getElementById("pixel");
   spaceW = screen.height - div.height;
   spaceH = screen.width - div.width;
   setInterval(moveIt, 1000);
}

function moveIt()
{
   div.style.top = (100*Math.random()) + "%";
   div.style.left = (100*Math.random()) + "%";
}
```

The thing is, it only works when I use the `setInterval`. I only want the div to move ONCE. I'll erase the `setInterval`, and then what?

Comment: Why the `setInterval()` if there is a click event (_"where you press a button and a div positions itself randomly"_) to call `moveIt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look through the documentation, you will see [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) fires at specific and regular intervals. If you want to only fire your function ONCE, use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) instead:

```js
function Init()
{
    div = document.getElementById("pixel");
    spaceW = screen.height - div.height;
    spaceH = screen.width - div.width;
    setTimeout(moveIt, 1000);
}
function moveIt()
{
    div.style.top = (100*Math.random()) + "%";
    div.style.left = (100*Math.random()) + "%";
}

Init();
```

```css
#pixel
{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="pixel"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

SetInterval repeats every given interval

setTimeout runs once when the timeout expires

Sounds like you need to use setTimeout if you'd like it run once

```
 function sayHi() {
  alert('Hello');
 }   
setTimeout(sayHi, 1000)
```

see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deshpandeakhil/SqRq2/) not created by me

Answer (score 0):

**If it works this way then declare a variable for the setInterval() then you can distroy that interval in the other function, like this varible.clearInterval()**

```
some=setInterval(moveIt,200);//this one in caller function.
some.clearInteraval();//here this statment should be in moveIt
```

> here you should declare some as global variable